# sty file not found on WSL

Tags: packages

I want to install fltpage package (https://ctan.org/pkg/fltpage) for my thesis. 
I'm using Windows 10 LTSC and NVIM v0.3.4 inside Windows subsystem for linux and TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019) with kpathsea version 6.3.1.

I have tried to put the .sty file everywhere `/home/myhome/txmf/ftlpage/fltpage.sty`, in `/home/myhome/txmf/tex/latex/ftlpage/fltpage.sty` , in `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fltpage/fltpage.sty`

After each try I typed `sudo $(which mktexlsr)`

but I still have the same message `File 'fltpage.sty' not found`

I will appreciate any help thank you very much in advance !

And for info the output of `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMF` is

```
{{}/home/vincent/.texlive2019/texmf-config,/home/vincent/.texlive2019/texmf-var,/home/vincent/texmf,!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local,!!/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-config,!!/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var,!!/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist}
```

EDIT : Solution is to place the file like
`/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/fltpage/fltpage.sty` AND to remove ls-R file in the texmf tree. Thank you @Ulrike Fischer !

Comment: `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/fltpage` looks like a good place.

Comment: Thank you for your response but it did not work.

Edit : post inadvertently too soon
My file structure is as follow : `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/fltpage/fltpage.sty`

I still have the same error. I'm wondering if it could be my vimtex plugin playing a role...

Comment: do you have an lsr file in this texmf tree? If yes better delete it.

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes (although I don't what you are wearing right now) ! That was the problem ! Thank you very much !
Just to understand the ls-R file is not updated after each `sudo $(which mktexlsr)`

Comment: Sorry I don't have WSL and I really don't know what you need to do there to update the ls-R (but `which` as command sounds odd).

Comment: please don't edit solutions into the question it messes up the Q&A format of the site. It's fine to post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to place the file like `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/fltpage/fltpage.sty`
AND to remove `ls-R` file in the texmf tree.

Thank you @Ulrike Fischer !

Comment: thanks:-) . . .